# Permission Denied Error While Loading Document in MarkLogic from filesystem

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have MarkLogic installed on Redhat and I am trying to Load XML Document in MarkLogic using following Query

```
xdmp:document-load("/root/abc/Set1/pqr.XML",
            <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
              <uri>/pqr</uri>
              <format>xml</format>
              <permissions>{xdmp:default-permissions()}</permissions>
             <collections>
              <collection>test1</collection>
              <collection>test2</collection>
              <collection>test3</collection>
              <collection>test4</collection>
            </collections>
            </options>)
```

While executing above query on qconsole i am getting following error,

**[1.0-ml] SVC-FILOPN: xdmp:document-load("/root/abc/Set1/pqr.XML", pqrxml) -- File open error: open '/root/abc/Set1/pqr.XML': Permission denied**

I am using root user for redhat, admin user for MarkLogic and file **pqr.XML** is also available in **/root/abc/Set1** location.

Please guide me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 3):

The MarkLogic process runs as `daemon` user in RedHat. Make sure that user has read access to the file you try to load.

HTH!